# Material ui Popup with pointer

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

How can I create a Popup similar to an image attached with @Material-ui?

https://material-ui.com/

I tried with Popover. But Popper doesn't have a pointer.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Customize material-ui popover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50057293/customize-material-ui-popover)

Comment: Hi Claire, no, that seems a workaround. looking for a clean solution :-)

Answer (score 0):

Add this prop, to your popover component

PaperProps={{
style: {
background: 'none',
boxShadow: 'none',
},
}}